# Jersey 2.29.1 Response Encoding Issue with AWS Api Gateway+ AWS Lambda +Scala

Tags: scala, aws-lambda, character-encoding, jersey, iso-8859-1

I am having an issue in returning special characters(Chinese characters).
My flow is following 
AWS API Gateway calls Lambda (Contains Jersey 2.29.1)

Before returning response I am printing it in logs and on cloud-watch logs, I can see the response as following

```
{
    "names": [
    "骅威文化股份有限公司"
     ]
}
```

But when the response returned by the API is following(which is encoded in ISO-8859-1)

```
{
    "names": [
    "éªå¨æåè¡ä»½æéå¬å¸"
     ]
}
```

The code which I am using to return the response is

```
return Response.status(200).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").entity(gson.toJson(response)).build()
```

with these annotations to the returning method

```
@Consumes(Array(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
@Produces(Array(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
```

I have tried all the options mentioned in community blogs like changing the annotation to add "UTF-8" string in the produces annotation like `@Produces(Array(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8"))`
. To add the Content-Type header in the Response builder code I used is `return Response.status(200).encoding("UTF-8").header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").entity(gson.toJson(response)).build()`.

After this, I cloned the [jersey repo](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey) and looked in the code that the default encoding used by it is "ISO-8859-1". Here you can see line#32 of org.glassfish.jersey.jdk.connector.internal.HttpParser contains `private static final String ENCODING = "ISO-8859-1";`

Is there a way to either set some property or add some custom Filter so that I can update this encoding to use UTF-8 and have a correct response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you try this one in your lambda handler?

```
LambdaContainerHandler.getContainerConfig().setDefaultContentCharset("UTF-8");
```

[reference](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container/issues/269#issuecomment-513293076)